# Come posso rendere "to be on sick leave" in italiano?

Tags: translation, phrase-request

In inglese, si usa la locuzione "to be on sick leave" quando si ha un permesso per assentarsi dal lavoro a causa di una malattia o di un problema di salute del lavoratore.

In castigliano e in catalano, abbiamo le espressioni "estar de baja" e "estar de baixa", rispettivamente, per esprimere questa stessa idea (si tratta di modi di dire del linguaggio comune, in linguaggio burocratico invece di "baja" si utilizzerebbe "situación de incapacidad temporal" o qualcosa del genere).

Come potrei esprimere questo in italiano?

Ho cercato sul [dizionario Sansoni](https://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_inglese/Inglese/S/sick.shtml) e sul [dizionario Collins inglese-italiano](https://www.wordreference.com/enit/leave), ma non ho trovato la locuzione "sick leave". Su [WordReference](https://www.wordreference.com/enit/leave), mi è apparso "essere in malattia", ma alla [voce "malattia" del dizionario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/malattia) non si trova "in malattia" e l'esempio che appare su WordReference mi sembra anche sospetto per una certa confusione di tempi verbali nella traduzione (e poi, "essere in malattia", se veramente si usa, non significherebbe "essere malato"?).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Il termine burocratico sarebbe **"Assenza per malattia"** o **"Congedo per malattia"**; io tradurrei quindi *to be on sick leave* con:

> Essere (o stare) in congedo per malattia

oppure

> Essere (o stare) assente per malattia

Si usa anche, ma solo come espressione informale:

> Mettersi in malattia

Anche "Essere in malattia" si usa proprio in questo senso (e non nel senso di "essere malato"), ma è anche questa un'espressione informale.

Ultima espressione (di nuovo informale) è

> Darsi malato

ma in questo caso assume anche una sfumatura più negativa, diciamo "truffaldina".

Comment: Aggiungo infine, ma solo a titolo informativo, l'espressione "marcare visita", ma qui scivoliamo nel gergo da naja, e si può usare solo in modo scherzoso, nel senso di accampare motivi di salute per evitare di fare qualcosa.

Comment: E si direbbe anche "essere in assenza per malattia"?

Comment: @Charo sì, ma secondo me in questo caso sarebbe meglio "Essere assente per malattia" ("Essere in assenza" non mi suona bene, anche se è comprensibile). Ho preso il tuo suggerimento e aggiornato la risposta

Comment: Ah, OK, grazie, @RiccardoDeContardi!

Answer (score 8):

Ciò che hai letto su WordReference è ciò che più comunemente viene detto.

> Sono malato, quindi sono in malattia.

Essere "in malattia" non significa "essere malato", ma è proprio un modo di dire "to be on sick leave".

In [questo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xhq5MNzWfHQ) spezzone del film "Cado dalle nuvole" di Checco Zalone tra il minuto 00:30 e 1:00 (in particolare intorno al minuto 1:00) si dice

> Mio cugino [...] si sta girando il mondo in malattia.

Come viene spiegato nel video, suo cugino non è realmente malato, ma è appunto esonerato dall'andare a lavoro (è appunto "in malattia") perché ritenuto tale.

Comment: Nel video, prima di parlare di questo cugino, si dice: "Ti prendi una settimana di malattia e vieni. Ti faccio fare io il certificato del medico. Ho un amico medico mio". Quindi, si potrebbe anche dire "prendersi" +  espressione che indica una quantità di tempo + "di malattia"? Credo che "mi sono preso/a una settimana di malattia" sia più o meno l'equivalente del catalano "(m')he agafat una setmana de baixa".

Comment: Sì, in particolar modo in contesti colloquiali è un'espressione usatissima.

Answer (score 4):

In aggiunta alle precedenti, sicuramente corrette, io aggiungo l’espressione *essere in mutua.*

Questa espressione viene ancora usata dalle persone più anziane perché fa riferimento alla cassa mutua che gestiva le assenze per malattia prima della riforma sanitaria.

Infatti il Sabatini Coletti, per [mutua](https://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/M/mutua.shtml) riporta:

> **mutua** 
>  
>   **[mù-tua] s.f.** 
>  
>   1 Ente che, prima della riforma sanitaria,
>   gestiva, in forma mutualistica, l'assistenza medica e ospedaliera dei
>   lavoratori: operaio iscritto alla m.; ogni istituto che svolge servizi
>   di previdenza e assistenza nei confronti degli associati (oggi
>   sostituito sempre più freq. da ASL): medico della m. 
> 2 Ogni ente
>   associativo che fornisce ai propri membri determinate prestazioni
>   (sociali, sanitarie, assistenziali ecc.) in caso di particolari eventi
>   (malattia, incidenti, ritiro dal lavoro ecc.)
>
> **a. 1869**

Comment: Questa risposta indica la frase più univoca legata al mondo del lavoro: si dice anche "mettersi in mutua", "chiedere la mutua", "prendersi tre giorni di mutua"; peccato che la citazione del dizionario non riporti questo uso.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica Giusto. Per non parlare di "mettersi in cassa malattia", anche se ormai obsoleta come espressione.

Comment: Qual è la ragione del downvote? Sono davvero sconcertata: questo mi causa perplessità. Forse quello che ha detto @linuxfan non è vero? Magari questa espressione non si usa più? È anche obsoleta come quella che ha menzionato Easymode44?  Qualcuno potrebbe chiarire, per favore?

Comment: @Charo va considerato che il linguaggio "ufficiale" non parla di *mutua*, non esiste più, di conseguenza il termine si può ben dire obsoleto. Questo non vuole dire che non sia più usato: le persone di una certa età lo usano, e i giovani lo capiscono perché l'hanno sentito dai genitori. È un po' come dire che *sordo* è obsoleto perché adesso si dice *audioleso*: nel linguaggio ufficiale/burocratico si evita di scrivere *sordo*, ma il termine è ugualmente ben vivo.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica:  E, infatti, nel linguaggio "ufficiale" spagnolo si parla di "encontrarse en una situación de incapacidad temporal", come puoi vedere, per esempio, [qui](https://salut.sindicat.net/media/salut/uploads/2020/03/10/contingencia_coronavirus_4_5996949220634920474.pdf). Ma la mia domanda è sulle espressioni che si usano nel linguaggio comune. Continuo a non capire la ragione del downvote. E alcune delle altre alternative si riferiscono veramente al linguaggio burocratico?